# Replace Element After 3 Clicks With Cookie Logging Script [HELP]

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, replace, element

Been trying to replace an element after 3 clicks on it with cookie logging. So the webserver remembers when 3 clicks have exceeded on a specific element and replaces it with url one. So it should of been simple but, I tried finishing mine and this is what, I came up with:

```
document.getElementById("replace1").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("replace1");

let count = 0;
function loadDoc() {    
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  let callback = function() {
  count++;    
  if (!(count >= 3 && this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)) { 
     localStorage.setItem("replace1",this.responseText);   
  }
  iframe1.click(callback);    
  xhttp.open("GET", "https://natevanghacks.com/replacements/yoinkexecutor2.html", true);
  xhttp.send(); 
  }
};
```

As predicted it won't work for some reason. All, I am trying to do is replace element after 3 clicks on it with the url one and webserver remembers the change so it doesn't return back to its default state. Whether with database or in Cookie, sessionStorage, localStorage.

Comment: Did you call your function?

Comment: callback is called